# isomorphism of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am finding it difficult to prove isomophism between two graphs especially when the basics such as number of vertices, degree sequence etc are same. If one tries to compare the adjacency matrix, the comparison holds only if the numbering of vertices is done correctly. Given a particular numbering of vertices, how does one correctly number the second graph under comparison? If we randomly number the vertices of second graph, and find the adjacency matrix of the two, how do we compare the two matrices? Also Counting cycles for comparison becomes difficult in complicated graphs. Is there a methodical step by step way to find isomophism between two graphs?
Request guide

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem (TL/DR: It's a very hard problem in general.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. To be specific, I tried to solve problems e1.1.18,1.1.19,1.1.20,1.1.21,1.1.22 from the book "Introduction to Graph Theory" by Douglas West.   The problems look simple once solution is known, but I am unable to get logical steps to arrive at those solutions. Another related difficulty is that showing isomorphism of compliments of graphs in above problems. The compliments are probably as complicated and therefore, trying to prove isomorphism by finding isomorphism in compliments appears difficult. Any help towards this, other than mentioned link is welcome. Thanks